# What is the mirror of an algebraic group?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, sg.symplectic-geometry, derived-categories, mirror-symmetry

**Background:** Kontsevich's homological mirror symmetry conjecture posits the existence of pairs $(X,\check X)$ with an equivalence of dg/$A_\infty$-categories
$$\mathcal F(X)=\mathcal D^b(\check X)$$
where $\mathcal F(X)$ denotes the Fukaya category of the symplectic manifold $X$ and $\mathcal D^b(\check X)$ denotes the bounded derived category of coherent sheaves on the algebraic variety $\check X$.

**Question:**

> What is the mirror symplectic manifold $X$ to an algebraic group $G=\check X$?

I'm happy to assume that $G$ is semisimple if that helps.

Comment: Mirrors of Abelian varieties are also Abelian varieties, no ?

Comment: Maybe, it is the Langlands dual group $G^\vee$.

Comment: @user66288 The Langlands dual is only defined if $G$ is reductive. More to the point, do you have any reason to expect this to be true, other than "because it'd be cool"?

Comment: John Pardon said in his post, we may assume that $G$ is semisimple. But semisimple implies reductive. I expect this because we see some work by Konstanze Rietsch on mirror symmetry of homogeneous spaces. She uses often the Langlands dual to define the mirror of some $G/P$. However, it is not clear to me how this work relates to the homological situation of Kontsevich.

Comment: @user66288 Doesn't this involve taking $G/P$ as the symplectic side of mirror symmetry (i.e. the mirror symmetry involves the Gromov-Witten invariants of $G/P$)? Here we take $G$ to be on the complex side.

Comment: If you want to see a discussion for homological mirror symmetry for non-trivial examples of $G/P$, look at Lekili-Pascaleff (https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8609). One point to keep in mind is that the mirror is a space equipped with a potential. This is because the CY structure doesn't compactify nicely at infinity.

Comment: @Will Sawin I think you are right. In this setup, the mirror dual of $G/P$ encodes quantum cohomology and Gromov-Witten invariants of $G/P$.

Comment: I was about to write an answer suggesting (a cohomologically shifted version of) the centralizer $J_0$ of a regular nilpotent element of the Langlands dual group, but then I realized you wanted to think about $G$ on the complex side...

Comment: For what it's worth: the wrapped Fukaya category of $G=T^\ast G_c$ is identified with modules for the homology of $\Omega G_c$ (or equivalently of the affine Grassmannian) under convolution. A result of Ginzburg (I believe) identifies this with the coordinate ring of $J_0$. Not sure if this is relevant to your question though.

Comment: Conjecture 1.10 on page 20 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.5922.pdf gives a proposal for a Landau Ginzburg mirror to split semi-simple algebraic groups. It also gives a log CY version of the kind that @MohammedAbouzaid is alluding to above. It's also worth noting that the conjecture does involve an open subvariety of the Langlands dual group as suggested by user66288.